# Git repository not found

Tags: git, github, osx-lion

I'm trying to use Git for the first time.

I did everything that github instructions said to do, but when I got to:

```
    git push -u origin master
```

I typed:

```
    /Users/name/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git push -u origin master
```

And got the error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also tried to set my git path to the above since it says git isn't found, but the path didn't work.  So I've just been typing the whole thing out.  When I did `sudo find / -name git`, it came up with the above directory for git, and also some other directories that I wasn't sure about, such as

- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git
- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/python/git_remote_helpers/git
- /Users/name/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/python/git_remote_helpers/git

and the one that I used:

- /Users/name/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git

I saw that all of the other commands to set up a git repository seemed to work ok.
Other commands to set up included

```
    mkdir fbPic2
    cd fbPic2
    <path to git>/git init
    touch README
    <path to git>/git add README
    <path to git>/git commit -m 'first commit'
    <path to git>/git remote add origin git@github.com:michcleary/fbPic2.git
    <path to git>/git push -u origin master #didn't work
```

I tried to look for `.git/config` but can't find it.

I hope someone out there knows about this.  It says that I need to get Git installed to do a Facebook app in the tutorial.  I have a Mac Mini with Lion installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute first step is to get Xcode to install the 'command line tools'.  Doing that will get the tools into /usr/bin - which is already in your PATH.  Go to "Xcode" :: "Preferences" :: "Downloads" :: "Components" where there should be an install "Command Line Tools".  If there isn't, go to "Xcode" :: "Open Developer Tool" :: "More Developer Tools" and download the most recent command line tools.  Now, 'git' will be in your path.  Should also be that 'git help ' works too!

Now configure git with (as suggested by @johnsyweb):

```
git config --global user.name "full name"
git config --global user.email  "email address"
```

and for GitHub:

```
   git config --global github.user "github username"
   git config --global github.token "github token"
```

where you will need to follow the GitHub directions to get your token.  You'll also need to carefully follow the GitHub SSH instructions.
After the above 'git config' commands you will have a ~/.gitconfig file ready to go.

Presumably you have created a GitHub repository already.  If not, you must.  [It doesn't look like you have a public repository yet.]  After creating one,  the easiest approach to getting a local repository setup is simply:

```
git clone git@github.com:michcleary/fbPic2           # cut and past the URI from the GitHub page after creating a repo
cd fbPic2
echo "more stuff" >> README.md
git add 
git commit -m 'stuff'
git push
```

Done!

Comment: Thank you so much!  It says that tokens aren't used anymore in the github instructions.  Also, when I did the clone command, it says I cloned an empty repository.  I used git add to add my project elements to git and committed them, which looked good.  When I did git push, it said "ERROR:Repository not found. fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try 'git remote show origin' to confirm that you can connect to the GitHub repository.

Comment: I did git remote show origin, and it says:* remote origin, Fetch URL: git@github.com:michcleary/fbPic2, Push URL: git@github.com:michcleary/fbPic2, HEAD branch : (unknown), Loal branch configured for 'git pull': master merges with remote master

Comment: I ran through your commands above after clone and all looked good except the push: git push, and it said ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

I spend a couple of weeks on this and came to the conclusion that the git app on mac uses the https remote repository url but when using the term you need the ssh url.  To fix this I clicked the settings tab in the github app then pasted in the ssh url from the github site for my repo.

Comment: I recently had this happen to a coworker of mine. Not sure why it happens but now his GitHub Gui shows duplicate branches. TY for the fix we looked for a while on this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you add `<path to git>` to your `PATH` environment variable. You will probably do this by editing `${HOME}/.bashrc` and adding:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:<path to git>
```

The remote repository certainly exists at https://github.com/michcleary/ .

It looks like you haven't configured Git locally with your name and email address, which is why you can't see a Git configuration file.

There are a number of ways of doing this, but I suggest you follow the instructions from GitHub's ["Set your user name, email and GitHub token"](http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/) page to set these up for all Git instances on your local machine:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Firstname Lastname"
$ git config --global user.email "your_email@youremail.com"
```

This will add these values to `${HOME}/.gitconfig`.

Repository-specific values will exist in `/path/to/fbPic2/.git/config` (`.git` is a hidden directory).

You should set these configuration items *before* issuing any other `git` commands such as `init` or `commit` or `push`.

I also recommend checking out GitHub's ["SSH Issues"](http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/) page as that is often helpful for first-time GitHub users.

Comment: I saw in the facebook tutorial (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) it says to use the following command: git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git         and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the user did not have appropriate permissions. After I used the user with proper permissions the error vanished.

Comment: You might want to add some extra information to you answer, like *how* someone would go about this.